# Python - [Error: "TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"] - Paso un argumento a una función pero me devuelve error NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica para listar el espacio utilizado en las unidades de almacenamiento, para ello almaceno (en el caso de windows) el resultado del comando

```
storage = subprocess.getoutput('fsutil fsinfo drives')
```

Almaceno las unidades en un array para despues mediante un bucle crear un botón QPushButton por cada unidad que exista de forma dinámica.
El código mediante el cual creo los botones es el siguiente:

```
# la variable -unidades contiene todas las unidades de almacenamiento (C:/, D:/ ...)
for x in unidades:
                buttonUn = QPushButton(QIcon("icons/storage-device.png"), x)
                buttonUn.clicked.connect(self.infoUnidades(x))
```

El problema está cuando clico el botón me aparece el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
</code>
</pre>
```

He probado a poner la expresión -lambda pero en ese caso solo me pasa como parámetro el último elemtento del array -unidades. 
La función infoUnidades la utilizaría para extraer la memoria de la que dispone la unidad y saber cuanto espacio de disco tengo libre por unidad. 
Así quedaría la función:

```
def infoUnidades(self, unidad):
        free = subprocess.getoutput('fsutil volume diskfree ' + unidad)
        print(unidad)
        print(free)
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar ese error?
Muchas gracias de ante mano !

Comment: Hola. No estás devolviendo ningún dato con `infoUnidades`. Entonces al hacer click que espera que esta función retorne algún valor en realidad no estás devolviendo nada, es decir, `None`. Con `print` solo imprimes por pantalla. Intenta colocar un `return` con el valor que necesitas que devuelva.

Comment: Si pongo return "" me devuelve el mismo Error pero en vez de con 'NoneType' pone "TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'", si pongo un 0 me devuelve el mismo Error pero con -int "TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'". He visto que mucha gente utiliza funciones en python sin return, creo que no es necesario el utilizar return siempre únicamente en los casos que necesites retornar un valor, yo en este caso no necesito porque es lo que dices únicamente estoy imprimiendo por consola los datos para testear primero que funciona bien. Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: Debes poner `return free`

Comment: He probado con return free y devuelve el mismo error de 'str'

Comment: He probado como dices pero por lo visto en vez de pasar la letra de la unidad (Como por ejemplo C:/ ) me devuelve un valor booleano.
Lo intento concatenar para pasarselo al comando -fsutil volume diskfree <unidad>
pero al ser un valor booleano no funciona :S

Comment: @Adrian No es correcto lo que dices en el comentario. Al margen de lo que devuelva la función, está mal la forma en que se asocia al botón, porque la está llamando dentro de `.connect()`. El parámetro que espera `connect()` ha de ser de tipo funcion y no del tipo que la función retorne. Por eso tampoco funciona si hace que retorne una cadena, o un entero. Es irrelevante lo que la función retorne, el problema es que no hay que llamarla dentro de `.connect()`

Answer (score 2):

En algunos contextos (y tú te has encontrado con uno de ellos) hay funciones a las que como parámetro les tienes que pasar *otras funciones* (pero no llamarlas, ya que quien las llamará será la función en cuestión).

Por ejemplo, si queremos que al pulsar el botón se imprima "Hola", preparamos una función que haga eso:

```
def imprime_hola():
    print("Hola")
```

Y se asociará con el botón así:

```
buttonUn.clicked.connect(imprime_hola)
```

Observa algo muy importante. Estamos pasando el nombre de la función "sin más", es decir `imprime_hola`. En concreto  **no estamos pasando `imprime_hola()`** con unos paréntesis al final, porque si hiciéramos eso lo que ocurriría sería que Python ejecutaría esa función en ese momento (y no cuando el botón se pulse más tarde), y lo que es peor, la acción asociada con el botón sería _el valor retornado por `imprime_hola()`. Ese valor en este ejemplo es `None`, así que a `.connect()` le estarías pasando `None`.

Eso de momento no es un error, el botón se limita a almacenar `None` como la acción a ejecutar cuando sea pulsado. Pero claro, cuando luego lo pulses intentará ejecutarlo así: `None()` y ahi tendrás el error de que None no es ejecutable.

El problema es que en tu ejemplo queremos pasar un parámetro a la función. Es decir, sería algo más parecido a:

```
def saluda(nombre):
   print("Hola", nombre)
```

¿Cómo asociamos esa acción al botón para que imprima por ejemplo "Abu"? Si hacemos `.connect(saluda)` sin parámetros no va a funcionar porque cuando se pulse el botón se ejecutará `saluda()` (porque el botón siempre va a hacer eso, llamar a la función que tú le pases, pero *sin pasarle ningún parámetro*). Y si ponemos `.connect(saluda("Abu"))` tampoco va a funcionar por lo que ya dijimos antes: la acción asociada será `None`.

Para estas cosas resulta útil la `lambda`. La `lambda` es una forma de escribir una función muy simple "en una sola línea". Se usaría en este caso así:

```
buttonUn.clicked.connect(lambda: saluda("Abu"))
```

La función que le estamos pasando ahora al botón es la lambda, la cual no recibe ningún parámetro y tiene por "cuerpo" la llamada a `saluda("Abu")`. Cuando el botón se pulse, se ejecutará esa lambda (sin parámetros), y la lambda a su vez ejecutará `saluda()` pasándole el parámetro "Abu". ¡Objetivo conseguido!

Pero ¿y si queremos que el parámetro en vez de ser una cadena prefijada sea tomado de una variable? Algo así:

```
nombre = "Abu"
buttonUn.clicked.connect(lambda: saluda(nombre))
```

Esto parece que debería funcionar. La acción asociada es la lambda. Cuando el botón se pulse se ejecutará esa lambda (sin parámetros) la cual llamará a `saluda()` pasándole como parámetro `nombre`. Ya que `nombre` en ese momento tiene el valor `"Abu"` ¡Objetivo logrado de nuevo!

Pero aquí hay un matiz muy sutil. El valor de `nombre` se mira **en el momento que se ejecuta la `lambda`** y no en el momento que ésta se define. Es decir, si hemos cambiado `nombre = "Pepe"` antes de pulsar el botón, cuando el botón se pulse `nombre` valdrá "Pepe" y eso será lo que se imprimirá.

Esta es la razón por la que si defines varios botones dentro de un bucle e intentas usar el truco de la lambda para que cada botón imprima un nombre diferente, no va a funcionar como esperabas. Todos imprimirán lo mismo: el último valor del bucle, porque ese es el valor que queda en la variable `nombre` para cuando cualquiera de los botones vaya a ser pulsado.

### Solución

El truco es usar la siguiente (y chocante) sintaxis:

```
nombre = "Abu"
buttonUn.clicked.connect(lambda nombre=nombre: saluda(nombre))
nombre = "Pepe"
```

Ahora, al pulsar el botón saldrá "Hola Abu" y no "Hola Pepe" ¿cómo es posible? Pues porque hemos añadido a la `lambda` un parámetro (`nombre`) que dice qué es lo que tiene que imprimir, pero a la vez le hemos dado a ese parámetro un valor por defecto para el caso en que al llamarla no se le pase nada (como de hecho ocurrirá cuando se pulse el botón). El valor por defecto para ese parámetro es lo que haya en `nombre` ("Abu") **en el momento en que la lambda está siendo definida**, por lo que no cambiará de valor aún si más adelante la variable cambia.

En definitiva, para tu caso la solución es:

```
for x in unidades:
    buttonUn = QPushButton(QIcon("icons/storage-device.png"), x)
    buttonUn.clicked.connect(lambda x=x: self.infoUnidades(x))
```

## Actualización

Aunque todo lo explicado anteriormente es correcto en lo que respecta a cómo se debe pasar una acción a un botón y cómo lograr que la lambda funcione con el valor de la iteración del bucle que corresponda en vez de con el valor final, sin embargo al introducir esta "teoría" en una aplicación PyQt5, ésta parecía fallar, pues lo que recibía `self.infoUnidades()` era siempre `False` en lugar del valor de la unidad correspondiente.

La razón se halla en que cuando se pulsa el botón, Qt llama a la acción **y le pasa un booleano como parámetro**, si detecta que la función admite un parámetro. Esto no lo he encontrado documentado en ningún sitio, pero he llegado a esa conclusión mediante una serie de experimentos.

Por eso fallaba la solución. Ya que la lambda que usamos en `.connect()` admite un parámetro `x`, entonces Qt le va a pasar ese parámetro (con el valor `False`, no sé qué significa), y por tanto no se va a usar el valor por defecto `x` que habíamos especificado.

**La solución** a este nuevo problema es hacer que la lambda reciba **dos** parámetros. En el primero no le damos valor por defecto y será donde Qt meterá su `False` (que no nos interesa) y en el segundo será donde daremos el valor por defecto del bucle, y que luego pasaremos a `infoUnidades()`. Es decir, el bucle quedará así:

```
for x in unidades:
    buttonUn = QPushButton(QIcon("icons/storage-device.png"), x)
    buttonUn.clicked.connect(lambda _, x=x: self.infoUnidades(x))
```

Fíjate como ahora la lambda tiene dos parámetros. Al primero le he llamado `_`, siguiendo el convenio Python de llamar así a una variable cuyo valor no nos interesa. El segundo es la `x` que queremos pasarle a la acción.

Comment: Sisi ya he probado y funciona perfectamente ! Muchísimas gracias por implicarte y darme la solución. Estoy muy agradecido. Vale por mi perfecto, borramos cada uno nuestros comentarios para dejar la solución más limpia. Muchísimas gracias por todo otra vez.

Comment: Último detalle. Aquí se documenta que cuando se pulsa el botón, al _callback_ (es decir a la función que se va a ejecutar) se le pasa un booleano --> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked Al parecer el booleano significa si el botón está "marcado" o no (para los botones "marcables"). No sé bien a qué se refiere, pues no conozco apenas Qt.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por la info. Yo es que apenas llevo 2 días con Python y desconozco completamente como utilizar PyQt5, Python y todo lo que conlleva. A ver si con el tiempo me familiarizo más que por lo visto se puede hacer muchísimas cosas con Python. Gracias de nuevo por todo

Answer (score 0):

creo que el problema esta en ciclo for, ya que estas almacenando datos para el boton y luego se pisa en el siguiente ciclo, por eso usando lambda te muestra el ultimo disco. quizas deberias agregar x cantidad de botones para la cantidad de discos que el ordenador posea. o podes agregarle un ComboBox con todas las unidades y pasarlo como parametro. pero si o si vas a tener que usar el lambda

disco = self.ComboBoxName.currentText()

buttonUn.clicked.connect(self.infoUnidades(disco))

Comment: Lo raro es que a la hora de crear los botones los crea correctamente sin sobreescribir los nombres, pero a la hora de asignarles el evento al botón con lambda no da error pero siempre le asigna el último valor del array.
Es decir si pulso la Unidad C:/ y el último valor del array es D:/ me ejecuta todo el rato como si fuese C la unidad D.
He creado los botones con -globals()['buttonUn%d-%d' % (e, i)] para crear todos los botones con nombre diferente pero ni aún así, sigue haciendo lo mismo.